# How can i update <img src= links in wordpress website?

Tags: wordpress, docker, kubernetes

I created my WordPress website using the Duplicator plugin. Firstly i deployed it on a regular docker container on a machine with IP1, then, after i configured WordPress to work, i did 'docker commit' to it and then push it to my docker hub repo, then, i used this new image with configured WordPress on to deploy wp on my Kubernetes pods, but when i deployed it, the images won't show up and in f12 img `src=IP1/bla/bla/bla.jpg`

I did update my wp_options and wp_posts to my Kubernetes IP, but it still unchanged and show IP1 in src.
What should i do?

Comment: update your column and use https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/regexp.html#function_regexp-replace

Answer (score 1):

There are several different ways in the WordPress ecosystem of scanning the database for instances of an older IP or URL and replace it with a new one.

One is using WP CLI if you're comfortable using your terminal. You install WP CLI and then simply do
wp search-replace old-ip new-ip
You can add --dry-run to show you what it will do without making any actual changes.
There are several nice parameters to exclude tables, and others

Another is using a Plugin like Better Search Replace which basically does the same, but gives you a UI in the WordPress admin.

It's not recommended to do direct queries on the db as suggested in the comment, because some instances of the URL or IP in your case can be stored in a serialized array, that can break if the old and new URLs don't have the exact same length.

The Plugin and wp cli approach ensure this doesn't happen and serialized arrays are correctly updated.